# html page not showing (only in debuging tho)

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, triggers

I need to display a specific html output following a condition on a variable ("tvs" a boolean).

I created the 2 html files in another spreadsheet and tested them OK.
Then I copy&pasted the samples in my much bigger spreadsheet and it doesn't work. Well, it **works when i debug** each 'show' functions but not in the execution of the spreadsheet.

My script goal is to detect change in a column (process info near the change occurred), then launch modal dialogs from html files (2 possible files).

**GS code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var celluleRef = e.range.getA1Notation()
    GLOBALVAR.setProperty('CELLREF', celluleRef);
    var cas = DetectCas(celluleRef) // do stuff, return cas = 0 or 1 or 2.

    if (cas == 0) {
        return
    }

    var tvs = SiTvs(celluleRef) // do stuff, return tvs as boolean.
    tvs ? showPageTvs() : showPageVide();
}

function showPageTvs() {
    //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("cas : page tvs") //THIS SHOWS when called
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var htmlTvs = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('PageTvs')
                  .evaluate()
                  .setHeight(600);
    ui.showModalDialog(htmlTvs, 'Confirmation');
}

function showPageVide() {
    // SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("cas : page vide") //THIS SHOWS when called
    var htmlVide = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('PageVide')
                  .setWidth(400);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
                  .showModalDialog(htmlVide, 'Confirmation');
}
```

Then the html files :

**PageVide.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    body{
  font-size:25px;
}
input.largerCheckbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    Gamme vide, quelle est votre action ?<br><br>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="google.script.run.processForm(this)">
    <div>
    <input class="largerCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="ConfP" name="ConfP">
    <label for="ConfP">Confirmation totale Prod</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input class="largerCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="ConfQ" name="ConfQ">
    <label for="ConfQ">Confirmation totale Qls</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br>
   <input class="largerCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="Tvs" name="Tvs">
   <label for="Tvs">TVS :</label>
    </div>
    <input style="font-size:25px" type="text" name="TvsText"><br><br>
    <input style="font-size:25px; float: left" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <input style="font-size:25px; float: right" type="button" value="Annuler" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**PageTvs.html :**
I add that function "decoupe" just add some checkboxes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
body{
  font-size:25px;
}
input.largerCheckbox {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
p {
  text-indent: 10%;
}
fieldset {
input[type=checkbox] { 
    text-indent: 20%;
}
}

      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Gamme en TVS, quelle est votre action ?<br><br>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="google.script.run.processForm(this)">
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" id="ConfP" name="ConfP">
    <label for="ConfP">Confirmation totale Prod</label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" id="ConfQ" name="ConfQ">
    <label for="ConfQ">Confirmation totale QLS</label>
    </div>
       <p>Confirmation partielle :
    <fieldset>
    <?!= decoupe() ?>
    </p>
    </fieldset>
<br>
    <input style="font-size:25px; float: left" type="submit" value="Valider">
    </form>
    <input style="font-size:25px; float: right" type="button" value="Annuler" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to understand why html **doesn't show (except in debug)** *and if anything hurt your eyes*, tell me !

Comment: They both show up for me when I use this `function showMyTestDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'),'Test');
}`  to load them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you do not have permission to call Ui.showModalDialog() because onedit is a simple trigger.

The following works on an installable trigger but not on a simple trigger:

```
function showMyTestDialog1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'), 'Test1');
}
function showMyTestDialog2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'), 'Test2');
}

function onMyEdit(e) { 
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const a1 = e.range.getA1Notation();
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet2' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    e.source.toast('cond')
    let v = e.range.rowStart % 3 == 0;
    v ? showMyTestDialog1() : showMyTestDialog2();
  }
}
```

> If you had checked your execution log you would have seen an error like this:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call Ui.showModalDialog. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
    at showMyTestDialog2(ag1:5:26)
    at onEdit(ag1:16:31)
```

Comment: I dont think it's the answer because in PageTvs.html i use the return of a function "decoupe". So i think i need to create a template then evaluate it.  Someone could say hwo is right ?

Comment: Well I guess we can't really help you since we  don't have decoup or  DetectGas

Comment: i can give them but my problem is that : 1 it works separately, 2 it works when i launch the functions showPageTvs() or showPageVide() in debug mode BUT just not in real execution (i add that the functions fire the alert in real execution but no modal shows). i modify my question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I found something wrong with your style in PageTvs.html

```html
<style>
    body{
      font-size:25px;
    }
    input.largerCheckbox {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    p {
      text-indent: 10%;
    }
    fieldset {
    input[type=checkbox] { 
        text-indent: 20%;
        }
    }
</style>
```

You should put fieldset input[type=checkbox] next to each other.
Like this:

```css
fieldset input[type=checkbox] {
    text-indent: 20%;
}
```

w3schools: [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thank you. CSS is my latest "thing" to create in this spreadsheet but everything i (you) improove is GOOD !  (problem still there, i show these pages in debug mode but not normally)